# PostgreSQL Using Alias at Where Condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements

How to set condition to last_order field where last order is custom field created by max sql function and group by user's id :

```
SELECT "users"."id", "users"."name", "users"."email", "users"."type", "users"."created_at", MAX(TO_CHAR(order_details.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-dd HH24:MM')) AS last_order
FROM "users"
LEFT JOIN "order_details" on "order_details"."user_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM "roles"
    LEFT JOIN "role_users" on "roles"."id" = "role_users"."role_id"
    WHERE "role_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" and "slug" = 'member'
) AND "users"."status" in (0)
AND (LOWER(CAST("users"."id" as TEXT)) LIKE '%%'
OR LOWER(CAST("email" as TEXT)) LIKE '%%'
OR LOWER(CAST("last_order" as TEXT)) LIKE '%%'
OR LOWER(CAST("name" as TEXT)) LIKE '%%')
GROUP BY "users"."id"
ORDER BY "created_at" desc
```

I always get this error:

```
column "last_order" does not exist
```

How to use last_order?? i already assing it at right alias.

That query generated by datatables, the error cause is i used the alias name for datatables's search function, my datatables code just like below:

```
columns: [
    { data: 'id', name: 'users.id', class: 'text-center', orderable: false },
    { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
    { data: 'last_order', name: 'last_order', class: 'text-center', orderable: true },
    { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
]
```

Comment: Because you can't use an alias in the `where` clause. BTW you don't group by a lot of columns that you don't aggregate too

Comment: @juergend So, how to include max function field to where clause?

Comment: Use the `having` clause

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

- You cannot use column aliases defined in the `select` in the `where` clause.
- You cannot use aggregation functions in the `where` clause.

Move the condition to a `having` clause:

```
. . .
GROUP BY "users"."id"
HAVING LOWER(CAST(last_order as TEXT)) LIKE '%%'
ORDER BY "created_at" desc
```

I assume your `like` patterns are actually more interesting than `'%%'`.  And, you shouldn't be using `like` for date/time columns.  Just use appropriate equality/range comparisons or comparisons on the date parts.

Comment: And postgres probably throws an error if the selected columns are not in the group by clause

Comment: @juergend . . . Postgres supports the (optional) ANSI standard functionally that lets functionally dependent columns in the `GROUP BY`, so that is not a problem, assuming that `users.id` is unique.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes that's right, but my problem is, that query is generated by datatables when i use the search table, the query just like that, so i can't change the query statement, the only one i need is how i use the alias at where condition, or change the datatables column name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff And i try to use having, the result same "column "last_order" does not exist"